# overrode equals(),but not hashcode() (and I have my @SuppressWarnings)

Tags: java, generics, adt, hashcode

I'm getting the following error everytime I do -Xlint javac List.java:

**List.java:9: warning: [overrides] Class List overrides equals, but neither it nor any superclass overrides hashCode method
public class List implements ListInterface{**

My professor hasnt explained what hashCode is, but he told us to add these warnings:
@SuppressWarnings("overrides") [before our class definition]
and @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") [before our equals() method].

In his documentation, he says once we put the @SuppressWarnings("overrides"), we should not get that error. However, I did both above, yet I still get that error.

My equals() class is this:

```
public boolean equals(Object rhs){
            boolean eq = false;
            List<T> R = null;
            Node N = null;
            Node M = null;

            if (this.getClass() == rhs.getClass()){
                    R = (List<T>)rhs;
                    eq = (this.numItems == R.numItems);

                    N = this.head;
                    M = R.head;
                    while(eq && N != null){
                            eq = (N.item == M.item);
                            N = N.next;
                            M = M.next;
                    }
            }
            return eq;

    }
```

Any helpful tips would be great!

Comment: Check the javadoc of equals, it explains how hashcode is related to equals

Comment: Your professor is doing you a disservice if he is telling you to add @SuppressWarnings to your code.

Comment: I assume it actually still compiles, do you know the difference between a warning and an error? Why are you adding `-Xlint` if you intend to ignore the warnings?

Comment: Also, `List` is a terrible class name, because it clashes with one of the most imported collection interfaces, `java.util.List`.